# Minimum value without minus Value in SQL

Tags: ms-access

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | -14 | 7 |
| 6 | -20 | 7 |
| 7 | -5 | 8 |
| 7 | 2 | -1300 |
| 8 | -9 | 8 |
| 9 | -10 | 9 |
| 9 | 10 | -1300 |
| 10 | -15 | 9 |
| 10 | 15 | -1300 |

With this query

```
select colum1, sum(column2), min(column3)
from Table 
group by column1
```

We get

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | -14 | 7 |
| 6 | -20 | 7 |
| 7 | -1 | -1300 |
| 8 | -9 | 8 |
| 9 | 0 | -1300 |
| 10 | 0 | -1300 |

How can I get value 8 except of -1300 in row 3, and value 9 except of -1300 in row 5, and value 9 except of -1300 in row 6 ?

I mean in column3, I need minimum value except minus value (like -1300 replace with other minimum value)

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | -14 | 7 |
| 6 | -20 | 7 |
| 7 | -1 | 8 |
| 8 | -9 | 8 |
| 9 | 0 | 9 |
| 10 | 0 | 9 |

I can't use operator because it will remove the row so column2 value will be change. It won't return the proper record

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard SQL syntax, you would use `case`:

```
select column1, sum(column2),
       min(case when column3 > 0 then colum3 end)
from Table 
group by column1;
```

The equivalent in MS Access is:

```
select colum1, sum(colum2),
       min(iif(column3 > 0, column3, null))
from Table 
group by colum1
```

Comment: thank you sir it works on Sql but i am using ACCESS database.. Sorry for my mistake in tag.

Comment: i tried it in SQL database result is perfect but that query cant be use in Access.. can you help me with access database. thank you in advance..